# How to bind a model to a table in SAPUI5

Tags: binding, sapui5, sap-fiori

im trying to bind an entitySet from a oData-Service to a list.
My code looks like this:

```
var list = oView.byId("list");
    var requestModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel()
    .attachRequestCompleted(function(data) {
        var model = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
        model.setData(data.getSource());
        list.setModel(model);
    });

requestModel.loadData("/sap/opu/odata/sap/XXX_SRV/detailSet?$filter=XXX eq 'XXX'");
```

My service returns a array of detail-Objects as expected but i can't seem to find a way to bind them to the list.
Thanks

Comment: Why are you using a JSONModel if you have an OData-Service? Please use the ODataModel instead.

Comment: Because the ODataModel automatically inserts a $metadata tag and you can not use $metadata when you want an entity set

Comment: Sorry, this is nonsense. The ODataModel has been developed to access ODataService. There might be cases where the standard implementation does not fit, but in general it should be more than sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution:

At first i had to create a dummy Path in my list like this:

```
<Table class="sapUiResponsiveMargin" items="{/dummy}" id="table" width="auto">
```

When you can bind the url directly to the table:

```
    var url = "/XXX?$filter=XXX eq '" + XXX + "'";
    var table = oView.byId("table");
    table.bindItems({
        path: url,
        template: table.getBindingInfo("items").template
    });
```

Comment: This is not really 'empty items', but `{}` merely means 'binding to an unnamed relative path'. It may work, but if your table items aggregation is already relative, you may run into issues. Better bind to a dummy path `items="{/dummy}"` for instance

Answer (score 0):

To get started with the ODataModel try this [guide](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/index.html#docs/guide/6c47b2b39db9404582994070ec3d57a2.html). In general it is very easy.

- Instantiate the model like described in the guide.
- Set the model to the view.
- Make use of the binding syntax in XML views to trigger a request to load your entities.